# Pass variable from a select value to a javascript function CDATA string

Tags: javascript, jquery, cdata

Currently I have a basic javascript which will alert the value of a selection. I would like to tie this into a javascript function so instead of alerting the value, it replaces the value within the script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function cselect(){
    var CID = document.getElementById('country').value;
    alert(CID);
}  
</script>

<select id="country" onchange="cselect()">
    <option value="4242">US</option>
    <option value="4243">Canada</option>
</select>
```

I would like to pass the option value into the script below in place of the static value. Any help greatly appreciated!

```
<script>// <![CDATA[

           cii_EmbedProductLinks('Chairs','{{ prodID }}','4242', CI_LinkID); 

// ]]></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
var sub = $("body").html().replace('4242',CID);
$("body").html(sub);
```